# Hot water valve not working

Tags: plumbing

[image]

Trying to replace my kitchen faucet and I went to turn off the water -  cold water valve works fine - hot water just turns and turns and doesn't stop water flow.

I'm in a condo and have access to our water heater. Is there a quick way to fix/shut off hot water here so I can replace my faucet?

Or do I need to shut water off to the whole building :/

Thanks!

Comment: You sure it's not just the handle spinning on the shaft?  Try unscrewing the handle and grabbing the shaft w/ a vice-grips.  If that doesn't work there is quite likely a cutoff valve on your water heater. Be sure to turn off the thermostat if you do cut water (either input or output) there.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to your water heater, it will typically have a shut off valve on its entrance to allow being serviced.  If you can shut that off, that will kill the pressure on the hot water line, and you should be okay.
Open the hot faucet to confirm.

Given that, I would consider taking that shutoff apart and fixing it if you can.

Probably a worn out or deteriorated rubber washer.  Worse case if that is just attached to the plumbing by the nut behind it, you can replace the whole valve.

Take it with you to a store.